# increment step for thread inside loops

Tags: cuda

When I define row and col indices like:

```
rowIn = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;
colIn = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
```

and use the loop:

```
for ( ; rowIn < Rows; rowIn  += gridDim.y * blockDim.y)
...
for ( ; colIn < Cols;colIn += gridDim.x * blockDim.x)
```

In order to step do I have to use ,for the row index:

```
gridDim.y * blockDim.y
```

or  `gridDim.x * blockDim.y` ?

An the same goes for col index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are defining your problem in row/col, you only have to step row with gridDim.y * blockDim.y and so for the col.

Comment: :So,I have just to use the same gridDim.y * blockDim.y in the rows and in the cols?

Comment: :And this is true even if I don't use the same x and y grid dimensions?

Comment: I mean same for col with the dimension of x, so gridDim.x * blockDim.x